# Is there any other way to store image in phpMyAdmin other than the BLOB type?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using phpMyAdmin and I have been trying to store input images directly on phpMyAdmin as a `LARGEBLOB` type. However, it doesn't upload properly and I have encountered errors such as

> "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 2182024 bytes) in
>   D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Error.php on line 373" or
>   "Server is away."

I was pretty sure that I kept the images within the alloted limit (2046KiB) that a `LARGEBLOB` could allow (I am trying to upload an image of 1MB) but somehow I couldn't get to upload it somehow. So is there any other way to insert an image into phpmyadmin? or a remedy so I could keep using `LARGEBLOB`s?

I have seen people replying to others' posts about converting images to `base64` and uploading them as strings but I am not sure how that works or how to do it.

Please shine some light on this matter. Thanks!

Comment: You’re not inserting into phpmyadmin. It’s just the tool you try to use to insert into MySQL. Your server is set to have memory limits and it can’t handle that large things. Connect directly to the database by other means.

Comment: If I were to manual insert the image in the database code and import that code would it work ?

Comment: sounds more like a PHP issue ( `upload_max_filesize`,`post_max_size`, `memory_limi` ) - but you would be better storing just the path to the image otherwise the db will potentially become enormous. Base 64 encoded strings will not save space either

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are uploading blob image data to DB, the good and efficient method:

1. Upload the image to the folder
2. Keep the uploaded path in the data column

Comment: This is a good way to do so, but it doesn't solve OP's problem. *don't forget to set folder permission to stop unwanted access*

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this one and give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

So I have looked into using `VARCHAR` on my `phpMyAdmin` for my images and inputted there, the location of my image (i.e - images/car.jpg). And using this code -

```
<?php
require "dbconfig.php";
$query =  $query = "SELECT * FROM images";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$image = $row['image'];
}
?>
<img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" alt="">
```

I was able to find loophole around using `BLOB` for images. This, however does not store the image on the database but the file location. Therefore you should not lose the folder.